# ZingChart X-axis labels do not evenly space

Tags: javascript, zingchart

I am trying to get the X-axis (time) scaling to be consistently even.  Depending on the range I input to the graph (could be 1 hour, could be 11 hours), the spacing will not stay consistent.  As in the example below, for a two hour period, you would expect to see the center label at the 2:30 mark, but for some reason ZingChart is choosing 2:40 as the intermediate label.
I've tried playing with the 'max-labels' property, as well as autofit, but no luck.
[image]

Current code:

````
window.addEventListener('load', function() 
{
    //zingchart.EXPORTURL = 'http://naskep/zing/export/index.php';
    zingchart.render(
    {
    id: "myChart",
    width: "100%",
    height: "700",
    data:       {
                type: 'line',
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                title:      {
                            text: "Historical Trending Demo"
                            },
                plotarea:   {
                            margin: '50 100'
                            },
                plot:       {
                            marker: {size: '1'},
                            preview:    {
                                        type: "area", //"area" (default) or "line"
                                        'line-color': "#0099ff",
                                        'line-width': 2,
                                        'line-style': "dotted",
                                        'background-color': "#99cc00",
                                        alpha: 1,
                                        'alpha-area': 0.1
                                        }
                            },
                scaleX:     {
                            //labels: myLabels,
                            autoFit: false,
                            transform: {
                                        type: "date",
                                        all: "%m/%d/%y %g:%i:%s %a"
                                        },
                            'max-labels': 6,
                            step: "minute",
                            'max-value': <?php echo $endtime; ?>,
                            zooming: true,
                            },
                scaleY:     {
                            zooming: false,
                            minorGuide: {
                                        lineColor: '#7F8C8D',
                                        lineWidth: 3
                                        },
                            minorTick:  {
                                        lineColor: '#7F8C8D'
                                        },
                            minorTicks: 1,
                            tick:       {
                                        lineColor: '#7F8C8D',
                                        lineWidth: 1
                                        }
                            },
                crosshairX: {
                            marker:     {
                                        alpha: 0.5,
                                        size: '7px'
                                        },
                            plotLabel:  {
                                        borderRadius: '3px',
                                        multiple: true
                                        },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                        backgroundColor: '#53535e',
                                        borderRadius: '3px'
                                        }
                            },
                preview:    {
                            adjustLayout: true,
                            borderColor: '#000000',
                            backgroundColor: '#EAEDED',
                            label:  {
                                    fontColor: '#CD5C5C'
                                    },
                            live: false,
                            mask:   {
                                    backgroundColor: '#7F8C8D'
                                    }
                            },
                series:     [{
                            values: myData
                            }]
                }
    })
}
);

</script>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the date time scale items are automatically spaced, so setting `maxItems` tends to mess the logic. However, if you really need to use `maxItems`, please also add

```
normalize : false
```

alongside it (in the `scaleX` object). Also, if acceptable to you, to be able to squeeze more labels, you can try the `"%m/%d/%y<br>%g:%i:%s %a"` format.

```js
// window.onload event for Javascript to run after HTML
// because this Javascript is injected into the document head
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // Javascript code to execute after DOM content

  // full ZingChart schema can be found here:
  // https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/json-configuration/
  let chartConfig = {

  "graphset": [

    {

      "type": "line",

      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",

      "title": {

        "text": "Outside Temp"

      },

      "plotarea": {

        "margin": "50 100"

      },

      "plot": {

        "marker": {

          "size": "1"

        },

        "preview": {

          "type": "area",

          "line-color": "#0099ff",

          "line-width": 2,

          "line-style": "dotted",

          "background-color": "#99cc00",

          "alpha": 1,

          "alpha-area": 0.1

        }

      },

      "scaleX": {
        normalize: false,
        "autoFit": false,

        "label": {

          "text": "Date/Time"

        },

        "transform": {

          "type": "date",

          "all": "%m/%d/%y %g:%i:%s %a"

        },

        maxItems: 3,
        itemsOverlap: true,

        "step": "minute",

        "max-value": 1585238400000,

        "zooming": true

      },

      "scaleY": {

        "label": {

          "text": "°F"

        },

        "minorGuide": {

          "lineColor": "#7F8C8D",

          "lineWidth": 3

        },

        "minorTick": {

          "lineColor": "#7F8C8D"

        },

        "minorTicks": 1,

        "tick": {

          "lineColor": "#7F8C8D",

          "lineWidth": 1

        },

        "zooming": false

      },

      "crosshairX": {

        "marker": {

          "alpha": 0.5,

          "size": "7px"

        },

        "plotLabel": {

          "borderRadius": "3px",

          "multiple": true

        },

        "scaleLabel": {

          "backgroundColor": "#53535e",

          "borderRadius": "3px"

        }

      },

      "preview": {

        "adjustLayout": true,

        "borderColor": "#000000",

        "backgroundColor": "#EAEDED",

        "label": {

          "fontColor": "#CD5C5C"

        },

        "live": false,

        "mask": {

          "backgroundColor": "#7F8C8D"

        }

      },

      "series": [

        {

          "values": [
            [1585227652204, 38],

            [1585227712217, 38],

            [1585227772231, 38],

            [1585227832245, 38],

            [1585227892259, 38],

            [1585227952271, 38],

            [1585228012285, 38],

            [1585228072299, 38],

            [1585228132312, 38],

            [1585228192327, 38],

            [1585228252340, 39],

            [1585228312353, 39],

            [1585228372366, 39],

            [1585228492394, 39],

            [1585228552408, 39],

            [1585228612421, 39],

            [1585228672435, 39],

            [1585228732448, 39],

            [1585228792462, 39],

            [1585228852476, 39],

            [1585228912490, 39],

            [1585228972504, 39],

            [1585229032516, 39],

            [1585229092529, 40],

            [1585229152544, 40],

            [1585229212556, 40],

            [1585229272571, 40],

            [1585229332589, 40],

            [1585229392599, 40],

            [1585229452611, 40],

            [1585229512624, 40],

            [1585229572638, 40],

            [1585229632652, 40],

            [1585229692666, 40],

            [1585229752680, 40],

            [1585229812693, 40],

            [1585229872707, 40],

            [1585229932722, 40],

            [1585229992734, 41],

            [1585230052747, 41],

            [1585230112761, 41],

            [1585230172775, 41],

            [1585230232789, 41],

            [1585230292801, 41],

            [1585230352814, 41],

            [1585230412828, 41],

            [1585230472843, 41],

            [1585230532856, 41],

            [1585230592869, 41],

            [1585230652883, 41],

            [1585230712899, 41],

            [1585230772910, 41],

            [1585230832924, 41],

            [1585230892938, 41],

            [1585230952951, 42],

            [1585231012969, 42],

            [1585231072979, 42],

            [1585231132992, 42],

            [1585231193011, 42],

            [1585231253019, 42],

            [1585231313033, 42],

            [1585231373046, 42],

            [1585231433060, 42],

            [1585231493073, 42],

            [1585231553087, 42],

            [1585231613101, 42],

            [1585231673114, 42],

            [1585231733127, 42],

            [1585231793142, 42],

            [1585231853155, 43],

            [1585231913169, 43],

            [1585231973181, 43],

            [1585232033196, 43],

            [1585232093209, 43],

            [1585232153222, 43],

            [1585232213237, 43],

            [1585232273249, 43],

            [1585232333264, 43],

            [1585232393276, 43],

            [1585232453292, 43],

            [1585232513305, 43],

            [1585232573317, 43],

            [1585232633332, 43],

            [1585232693345, 44],

            [1585232753359, 44],

            [1585232813372, 44],

            [1585232873386, 44],

            [1585232933400, 44],

            [1585232993414, 44],

            [1585233053426, 44],

            [1585233113440, 44],

            [1585233233467, 44],

            [1585233293482, 44],

            [1585233353494, 44],

            [1585233413509, 44],

            [1585233473522, 44],

            [1585233533535, 44],

            [1585233593548, 44],

            [1585233653562, 45],

            [1585233713576, 45],

            [1585233773591, 45],

            [1585233833604, 45],

            [1585233893617, 45],

            [1585233953631, 45],

            [1585234013644, 45],

            [1585234073658, 45],

            [1585234133671, 45],

            [1585234193685, 45],

            [1585234253698, 45],

            [1585234313714, 45],

            [1585234373724, 45],

            [1585234433740, 45],

            [1585234493752, 46],

            [1585234553766, 46],

            [1585234613779, 46],

            [1585234673793, 46],

            [1585234733806, 46],

            [1585234793820, 46],

            [1585234853834, 46],

            [1585234913847, 46],

            [1585234973862, 46],

            [1585235033874, 46],

            [1585235093889, 46],

            [1585235153902, 46],

            [1585235213917, 46],

            [1585235273929, 46],

            [1585235333943, 46],

            [1585235393956, 47],

            [1585235453969, 47],

            [1585235513984, 47],

            [1585235573998, 47],

            [1585235634011, 47],

            [1585235694024, 47],

            [1585235754037, 47],

            [1585235814051, 47],

            [1585235874065, 47],

            [1585235934079, 47],

            [1585235994092, 47],

            [1585236054106, 47],

            [1585236114120, 47],

            [1585236174132, 47],

            [1585236234147, 47],

            [1585236294159, 47],

            [1585236354173, 47],

            [1585236414187, 47],

            [1585236474202, 47],

            [1585236534214, 47],

            [1585236594228, 47],

            [1585236654241, 47],

            [1585236714254, 47],

            [1585236774270, 47],

            [1585236834283, 47],

            [1585236894297, 47],

            [1585236954309, 47],

            [1585237014325, 47],

            [1585237074336, 47],

            [1585237134349, 47],

            [1585237194365, 47],

            [1585237254378, 47],

            [1585237314391, 47],

            [1585237374404, 47],

            [1585237434419, 47],

            [1585237494432, 47],

            [1585237554446, 47],

            [1585237614460, 47],

            [1585237674472, 47],

            [1585237734487, 47],

            [1585237794499, 47],

            [1585237854513, 47],

            [1585237914527, 47],

            [1585237974541, 47],

            [1585238034555, 47],

            [1585238094568, 47],

            [1585238154581, 48],

            [1585238214595, 48],

            [1585238274608, 48],

            [1585238334623, 48],

            [1585238394636, 48]
          ]

        }

      ]

    }

  ]

};

  // render chart
  zingchart.render({
    id: 'myChart',
    data: chartConfig,
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
  });
});
```

```css
.zc-html, .zc-body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.chart--container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 530px;
}

.zc-ref {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="zc-html">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ZingSoft Demo</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="zc-body">
    <!-- CHART CONTAINER -->
    <div id="myChart" class="chart--container">
      <a class="zc-ref" href="https://www.zingchart.com/">Powered by ZingChart</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```